# How to generate compile_commands.json for a C++ Bazel project

Tags: c++, bazel

In a C++ [Bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp.html) project, I want to use tools like [Clang Tools](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html) or [RTags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags), etc.

For that I need to generate a [compile_commands.json](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) file.

The solution is trivial for CMake with the [CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html).

For simple Makefiles you can still use the [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) tool.

However AFAIK there is no built-in solution for C++ Bazel projects.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Extra information:**

- **Bear** is currently not working with Bazel: [this issue](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear/issues/170)
- a good documentation concerning **compile_command.json** can be found [here](https://sarcasm.github.io/notes/dev/compilation-database.html).

**Suggested solutions:**

After Googling about that I found [gist:Basics of generating a compile_commands.json file with Bazel](https://gist.github.com/bsilver8192/0115ee5d040bb601e3b7).

It works fine and I have written 
[an automated solution with bash scripts](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/Bazel_and_CompileCommands) <- my solution

*Alternative:*

Also on GitHub, you can find:

- [Kythe:](https://github.com/google/kythe/blob/master/tools/cpp/generate_compilation_database.sh) uses Bazel action listeners
- [github.com/grailbio/bazel-compilation-database:](https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-compilation-database) provides a script and a bazel rule.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the alternatives listed by other answers...

[Hedron's Compile Commands Extractor for Bazel (GitHub)](https://github.com/hedronvision/bazel-compile-commands-extractor) was just released and does what you want, I think. From the README, its goal is to "provide Bazel users cross-platform autocomplete for (Objective-)C(++) to make development more efficient and fun[..., and] export Bazel build actions into the `compile_commands.json` format that enables great tooling decoupled from Bazel."

Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes `hedronvision/bazel-compile-commands-extractor`... but I use it every day, and in my personal opinion it is very good!

Comment: Thanks would be great if there was an example project somewhere, having difficultly getting it to populate anything other than `[]` in compile_commands.json

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't an example project, but the README has a (new?) [section](https://github.com/hedronvision/bazel-compile-commands-extractor#usage) on setting up the tool with an existing project. If that still doesn't work, I'd file an issue in the repo because the author/maintainer is great about assisting new users.

Comment: Yep thanks, the author was super friendly and helpful and I got it working